# How to decrease frame rate of USB webcam 2.0 using openCV python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu-16.04, frame-rate, usb-camera

I am working on **ubuntu 16.04** and using a **USB 2.0 webcam.** I want to ***decrease the frame rate*** somehow since the project I'm working on requires face detection which really lags the video hence want to decrease the frame rate.

I've tried implementing the following code

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 15)
fps = int(cap.get(5))
print("fps:", fps)

while(cap.isOpened()):

    ret,frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k == 27:
        break
```

**I get the following error**

```
(python3:24100): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
```

If i set the frame rate in the above mentioned code to 30 (default frame rate) then i get a proper video, but if I change it I get the above mentioned error.

How can i decrease the frame rate either through code or even manually through settings (if there's a way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there is several ways you can do this but I would suggest first checking the capabilities of the webcam. You can do this by installing:

```
sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
```

And run:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
```

If the desired frame rate is not listed you can increase the value in `cv2.waitKey()` and time it with `time.time()` to get the frame rate you want.